# Getting mouse position in c#

Tags: c#, mouse-position

How do I get the mouse position? I want it in term of screen position.

I start my program I want to set to the current mouse position.

```
Location.X = ??
Location.Y = ??
```

**Edit:** This must happen before the form is created.

Comment: See newer answer further down which applies to today's version of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You should use [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx): "A Point that represents the cursor's position in screen coordinates."

Comment: Cursor.Position displays my tooltip way offscreen :(-

Comment: @Thomas Eyde: I'm guessing, but could that be because the mouse position is in screen coordinates and your tooltip position is relative to its parent window?  You might need to use `PointToClient`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had to to.

Answer (score 102):

If you don't want to reference Forms you can use interop to get the cursor position:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows; // Or use whatever point class you like for the implicit cast operator

/// <summary>
/// Struct representing a point.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
    {
        return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the cursor's position, in screen coordinates.
/// </summary>
/// <see>See MSDN documentation for further information.</see>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

public static Point GetCursorPosition()
{
    POINT lpPoint;
    GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
    // NOTE: If you need error handling
    // bool success = GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
    // if (!success)
        
    return lpPoint;
}
```

Comment: How to refer POINT type?

Comment: Add reference to System.Drawing

Comment: awesome solution. But you dont need to declare struct POINT. Just use Win32Interop.Structs namespace.

Comment: @ManpreetSinghDhillon Is Win32Interop.Structs available in .Net Core? If yes, under which nuget package / system reference?

Comment: @ManpreetSinghDhillon Using your own struct allows you to implicit cast it to whatever Point you use in your code, it's a bit smoother. If Win32Interop.Structs is enough for you then go sure go ahead and use it instead!

Comment: @Bose_geek sorry if it isn't clear but if you want to use another Point struct you just change that part of the code and reference whatever Point structure/class you want.

Answer (score 26):

[Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) will get the current screen poisition of the mouse (if you are in a [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx), the [MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) property will also get the same value).

To set the mouse position, you will have to use `Cursor.Position` and give it a new [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx):

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

You can do this in your `Main` method before creating your form.

Answer (score 20):

To answer your specific example:

```
// your example
Location.X = Cursor.Position.X;
Location.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

// sample code
Console.WriteLine("x: " + Cursor.Position.X + " y: " + Cursor.Position.Y);
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Windows.Forms;`, and adding the reference to it (right click on references > add reference > .NET tab > Systems.Windows.Forms > ok)

Answer (score 15):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition
```

[Gets the position of the mouse cursor in screen coordinates.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx)
"The Position property is identical to the Control.MousePosition property."

Comment: No need to be rude.  This is an alternative to the primary answer.  I just prefer this one because the other 'Cursor.Position' sounds like a text type cursor IMHO and 'MousePosition' is more obvious.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak sure, and yes I thought it maybe helpful.  I would have said something like this "Please could you include a little further information so I can see how this may differ from the answers given previously?"

Comment: @JanDvorak If you think one-liners don't help (btw, they do) then its not dependent on if the question is 1 day old or 3 yr old. +1 for alternative approach.

Answer (score 10):

To get the position look at the OnMouseMove event.  The MouseEventArgs will give you the x an y positions...

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mouseEv)
```

To set the mouse position use the Cursor.Position property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you need to get current position in form's area (got experimentally), try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "Current mouse position in form's area is " + 
    (Control.MousePosition.X - this.Location.X - 8).ToString() +
    "x" + 
    (Control.MousePosition.Y - this.Location.Y - 30).ToString()
);
```

Although, **8** and **30** integers were found while experimenting. It'd be awesome if someone could explain why exactly these numbers worked.

---

Also, there's another variant (considering code is in a form's code-behind):

```
Point cp = PointToClient(Cursor.Position); // Get cursor's position according to form's area
Console.WriteLine("Cursor position: X = " + cp.X + ", Y = " + cp.Y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the current cursor.
Use it to get the position of X and Y

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
int posX = Cursor.Position.X;
int posY = Cursor.Position.Y;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   internal static class CursorPosition {
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct PointInter {
     public int X;
     public int Y;
     public static explicit operator Point(PointInter point) => new Point(point.X, point.Y);       
  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out PointInter lpPoint);

  // For your convenience
  public static Point GetCursorPosition() {
     PointInter lpPoint;
     GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
     return (Point) lpPoint;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This answer was not eligible at the time the question was asked, but today you can use the static method `Mouse.GetPosition(IInputElement)` from the namespace `System.Windows.Input` in the PresentationCore assembly. This is valid from .NET Framework 3.0 and forward. Find more information on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Input_Mouse_GetPosition_System_Windows_IInputElement_

Example:

```
// displayArea is a StackPanel and txtBoxMousePosition is
// a TextBox used to display the position of the mouse pointer.
Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(displayArea);
txtBoxMousePosition.Text = "X: " + position.X +
    "\n" +
    "Y: " + position.Y;
```