# Handling ContextMenuStrip on ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview, contextmenu

I have a ListView with some items. The ListView has some group defined, some column, and some items are added. The ListView has set also the ContextMenu.

On *Opening* event of the ContextMenu, I shall check whether the context menu was opened on a ListView item. So, I did:

```
private void CtxMenuProcess_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenuStrip ctxMenuStrip = (ContextMenuStrip)sender;
    ListViewHitTestInfo hitTestInfo = LstViewAdminApp.HitTest(LstViewAdminApp.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));

    if (hitTestInfo.Item != null) {
        //....
    }
 }
```

Sadly, the hit doesn't happen.

I feel that the coordinates of the *ctxMenuStrip* are the wrong ones, but I tried a lot of "variants" without success, and the documentation of ListView.HitTest is very poor.

Anybody can help me?

---

Further investigation doesn't bring any solution. I'm starting to suspect about ListView control initialization. Here is the non default properties I have set:

- Activation = OneClick
- Columns = Colum[3]
- ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenu
- Dock = Fill
- FullRowSelect = true
- GridLines = true
- Groups = Group[3]
- HideSelection = false
- LabelWrap = false
- Sorting = Ascending
- View = Details

Comment: The `Location` property is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you SLaks. I've already noticed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443232/get-the-point-of-click-on-a-control

Comment: I think ListView.HitTest requires client coordinates. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I was working on something like this a while back, I found the code in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=5931) to be very useful.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use Windows messaging to solve my problem. The same code shall run also in Mono under Linux.