# How do I get the current screen cursor position?

Tags: c#

My objective is to get current position on the screen (out side the form), and save X, Y coords by press "C" for example.

I google and found some suggestion to use api hooks, but i wonder are there a way we can do this task purely in C# code (.NET Lib) ?

Please give me quick sample if possible because im new to c#.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "the absolute screen coordinates"? I.e. the x & y offset from the top-left corner of the screen (in pixels)?

Comment: @corlettk: yes, that's what i mean.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1316681/726631

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 12):

Just use:

```
Cursor.Position
```

or

```
Control.MousePosition
```

To get the position. You can then map the KeyPress event of the form:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 'c')
        MessageBox.Show(Cursor.Position.ToString());
}
```

The individual X and Y coordinates are two properties of the Position object.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

Comment: I tested your code , but when i pressed "c key, MessageBox isn't appear. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Maybe I went too fast. You say you're new to C#, but I don't know how new. Please forgive me if this is too basic, but did you add the KeyPress event in the form editor?

Comment: And of course KeyPress on form is a tricky thing, because if a control has the focus, then the event isn't fired.

Comment: Thanks MPelletier, i found the solution by set the Keypreview property = true for the form. regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found it interesting to share another approach for similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577528/21450783

Of course you can use curson position in background including a case when user doesn't interact with running program that does reading of cursor position.
By using new thread and periodically calling GetCursonPosition method it can be done easily - more you can find in the link.

PS: make sure you know total screen count connected to device so you know proper offset.