# Mimic Peripheral behavior using a programming language

Tags: c#, java, c++, controls, peripherals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)

Is it possible to mimic a peripheral , say , a mouse on one of the ports and write a program that could send a click to an (x,y) on the display ?

Comment: If you're interested in a C++ method for Windows, [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Are you monitoring a port as such or are you only interested in the actual click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  I did a MouseController for NUnitForms years ago.  Check out http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/

The source code of the mouse controller is at http://nunitforms.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nunitforms/trunk/nunitforms/source/NUnitForms/MouseController.cs?revision=32&view=markup

The key is using the Win32 function SendInput; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

The SendInput function takes a union as input, which is not easily supported by C#.  What I have done is to define two functions SendMouseInput and SendKeyboardInput that specify different input structs but call the same function.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SendInput", SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern int SendMouseInput(int cInputs, ref MOUSEINPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SendInput", SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern int SendKeyboardInput(int cInputs, ref KEYBDINPUT pInputs, int cbSize);
```