# Insert Label at Cursor Location

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I want to a label at the cursor position whenever the user clicks the form. From the answer in this question: [Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)

I have used

```
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Location = Cursor.Position;
        lbl.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
```

but when i run the program and click the form, nothing happens.

Pls what did i do wrong?

Comment: May be you should you use something like, `lbl.Location = new point(e.X, e.Y)`. Then, you want some text in your label as well, or you will not see it, because it will not be wide enough

Comment: I think the cursor.position is relative to the screen and not the form if I remember right. There is a way to get the position relative to the window.

Comment: The e.X and e.Y is the position where the user clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems. First, [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) returns the position of the cursor relative the *screen*, but the location of the label is measured relative to the *form*. This will result in the label being placed (most likely) somewhere the left and below of where you actually clicked. As [*Groo*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646770/insert-label-at-cursor-location#comment27456546_18646835) points out you could [`PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) to transform from screen coordinates to client (form) coordinates, but that's not necessary in this case, because the `MouseEventArgs` provides this already.

The second issue is that although you've set the `Visible` property to `true` (which actually isn't necessary since it defaults to `true`), you haven't actually given it any text to display. The label is added but you won't see be able to see it.

Use the location specified in the event (`e.Location`), and give the label some text (`lbl.Text`) so you can actually see it:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Location = e.Location;
    lbl.Text = "Hello World";
    this.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Finally, make sure you bind the event to your form correctly if you haven't already:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
}
```

Comment: +1 It's also worth mentioning that OP's code doesn't work because `Cursor.Position` returns the mouse location in screen coordinates, and label needs to be positioned in coordinates relative to its parent control (`Form`, in this case). Using the [`Form.PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) method would transform the `Cursor.Position` value into proper client coordinates (but it's unnecessary since event arguments already contain this information).

Comment: @Groo Thanks, I've added a detailed description of the issues for completeness.