# implement draggable ui like blockly

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently developing an application that allow the user to program some scripts. I've developed a "compiler" to analyse the script made by the user, but now i want create a visual editor with all the possibilities that the user have, something similar to this: [Blockly  - A visual programming editor](https://developers.google.com/blockly) .

I am currently using C# and I have no idea how to develop something like the above. I thought about doing my own draggable UI on top of my DSL, but not sure how to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For other Wpf developers trying to do something similar, I would not recommend doing this yourself but actually use a webpage within Wpf and then communicate with Blockly through that. I promise you that this will be a lot easier than actually trying to do this yourself.

[Use Blockly inside a WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799977/use-blockly-inside-a-webbrowser)

If you don't feel like recreating all your script generation code you could also create a custom xml generator for Blockly and then just print out which blocks are connected so like :

```
<block>
   <whileblock repeat="20"/>
<block/>
```

Then decipher this and generate your script from c# depending on the connected blocks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this: With Blazor it is now possible to create WPF programs and use razor files (HTML/CSS/JS/C#) for the UI description (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

This enables the usage of JS functions like Blockly directly inside the UI of the C# application, just by following the Blockly instructions (https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/web?hl=en) and using JSInterop of Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

Blockly is open source, so feel free to use it for your editor.  You don't really need to know much JavaScript in order to use the Blockly libraries, and there's a [support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/blockly).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with WPF. 
Using Drag and Drop you can get real closer.
Watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TksMljeFaV4) will help you get sense hou this mechanism works.
Try improving it slowly and playing with it.
2nd step will be to play with lists and drag and drop
[Like shown here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cipKJ2a6r8s) .
Improve it even more by using data you get from your mouse position,
a good way to do it [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp).