# Reach data from other event

Tags: c#, events, picturebox

We can get X and Y points which by mouse move on the picturebox like;

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     double Xcoordinate = e.X;
     double Ycoordinate = e.Y;

     label1.Text = Xcoordinate.ToString();
     label2.Text = Ycoordinate.ToString();
}
```

My question How can I get Xcoordinate and Ycoordinate from other events for ex; MouseClick event or my new defined function?

Actually I want to reach XCoordinate and Ycoordinate parameter from FormLoad. How can I do that?

Comment: thanks for minus. Pls give your opion dear genius

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp

Comment: I renewed my question . Just imagine my computer has two cursor (two mouse) And, I have two picturebox (picturebox1 and picturebox2). I want to reach cursor positions of these two pictureboxes from other event or function.

Comment: private void MoveCursor()
        {
            label1.Text = Convert.ToString(new Point(pictureBox1.????????
        }

Comment: I'm sorry, but how did you manage to have 2 mice and 2 cursors at once? I didn't know that was even possible. and how would you know which mouse position you need?

Comment: I mean, mouse1 on picturebox1 and will show us e.X and e.Y points at label1, likewise mouse2 on picturebox2 and it will show us points at label2.Anyway It is going crayz. Have a nice day

Comment: But I want to reach xcoordinate and ycoordinate parameter at FormLoad

Comment: So you have 2 pictureboxes, each with a mouse cursor, and you want to show the X and Y coordinates of each pointer in a label. Still doesn't explain how you managed to get hold of a second mouse cursor in the same Windows installation.

Comment: if u do for just one picturebox, I will do it more ;). But values should reacheable from MainForm

Comment: I ask again for the 3rd time how you got that second mouse pointer. You cannot have more than 1 mouse pointer at once on Windows unless you have an app that provides a second cursor. If you developed that app yourself you wouldn't ask this question because you'd know how to access that second mouse. So it has to be a 3rd party app, and the app you're using completely changes how you access this second mouse pointer. We literally cannot answer your question until you answered our question first: How did you get that second mouse?

Comment: ok calm down, I will use  2 joysticks in order to mouse. I am waiting your response about my above question. have a nice day

Comment: That solves the hardware issue, but not the software issues. I repeat again: Microsoft Windows does not have native support for more than 1 mouse cursor. Since you want to use C#, you'll have to use Microsoft Windows. Because Windows does not have native support for 2 or more mouse cursors, You'll have to use an extra piece of software for this cursor. My question is mainly: What software will you use for that? Depending on how this application works you need to access the secondary mouse pointer in a different way. As said, we need to know the software you use or we can't help you.

Comment: Dear Nate, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio C# (Student version). "Windows does not have native support for 2 or more mouse cursors" Please check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185522/Using-the-Raw-Input-API-to-Process-Joystick-Input

Comment: This is not with mouse cursors. Those crosses in those pictureboxes are not mouse cursors, they're pointers. In any case, you can access those picturebox pointer locations through the API for the picturebox. check MSDN for explanations on how to use those.

Comment: Dear nate, I am not expert but I know that u can use cursors in order to cross. Meanwhile could you read again my question. regards

Answer (score 1):

[Use Cursor Position property..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx)

```
 private void MoveCursor()
    {
       // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position, 
       // and set its clipping rectangle to the form.  

       this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
       Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
       Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
    }
```

Comment: I renewed my question
I am a dumb man. Just imagine my computer has two cursor (two mouse)
And, I have two picturebox (picturebox1 and picturebox2). I want to reach cursor positions of these two picturebox from other event or function.

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseMove` event happens to give you the mouse position. This is not included in other `EventArgs`. You can always get the mouse positon through [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The static method [Control.MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will get you the absolute position of the mouse pointer on the screen.   You can translate it using Control.PointToClient to get the coordinates local to a control of interest.

If I remember correctly, the one caveat is that MouseEventArgs gives you the mouse position as it was when the message was posted to the event loop, while Control.MousePosition gives you the position *right now*.  For most applications, this difference is probably not a big deal.

Comment: I renewed my question I am a dumb man. Just imagine my computer has two cursor (two mouse) And, I have two picturebox (picturebox1 and picturebox2). I want to reach cursor positions of these two picturebox from other event or function

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this Solution to Get co-ordinate of picture Box at the time of other event

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
            textBox1.Text = e.X.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
        }

       private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.X.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Or try It also

```
pictureBox1.MouseClick += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Mouse Clicked at X: {0} Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y));
```

Comment: Dear Aman, I want to kindly say to you. I defined xCorrdinate=e.X and yCoordinate=e.Y at OnMouseClick. Actually I want to reach xCoordinate and yCoordinate parameter from FormLoad. How can I do that? What should I search on internet. thanks