# TextBox issue in Touch-based WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch

I made a fully functional touch-keyboard within my WPF application using both XAML and C# (ofc). Currently, every key pressed on the keyboard registers the respective key in the text box; however, if the user touches the `TextBox` (which is welcomed...I do not want to prevent it) to position the cursor earlier in the `TextBox` to fix an error they might have typed **AND THEN** interact with the keys (as expected), the position they requested does not register and the keys continue to be entered on the end.

For example, user types(note the | acting as the cursor)::

```
Justin is awesome, bt that is because it is his birthday.|
```

User sees error in the word "but" spelled as "bt" so decides to touch the screen to position the cursor between **b** and **t** like so:

```
Justin is awesome, b|t that is because it is his birthday.
```

User expects then to *touch* **U** on the keyboard and it to be entered where the cursor appears to be...unfortunately (currently) it ends up like this:

```
Justin is awesome, bt that is because it is his birthday.U|
```

If I enable the mouse, the same thing happens (so it may not be exclusive to touch). If I plug in a keyboard after touching a position, I can type with said plugged-in keyboard no problem.

The implemented touch keyboard just wont read the position correctly. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp), the action seems to go no where because the `Cursor Position` goes from the `TextBox` to a `Button` (keyboard keys).

Here's a snippet of code for anyone to test (obviously can't provide the full keyboard):

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
  <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" />
  <Button x:Name="btnQ" Content="q" Click="btnQ_Click"/>
  <Button x:Name="btnW"   Content="w" Click="btnW_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
    private bool numberHitSinceLastOperator = false;
    private void HandleKeyboard(string key)
    {

        //Ternary operator
        string valueSoFar = numberHitSinceLastOperator ? txtBox.Text : "";
        string newValue = valueSoFar + key.ToString();
        txtBox.Text = newValue;
        numberHitSinceLastOperator = true;

    }
    private void btnQ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleKeyboard("Q");
    }

    private void btnW_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleKeyboard("W");
    }
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you can use the [SurfaceSDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx) (originally designed for the Surface and Pixelsense) for touch-enabled UI components. I used them in a wide range of projects and they work on all different types of touch screens with default WPF.

Comment: @StevenHouben Thanks for the suggestion! I looked into the SDK and will consider using it if I come across other issues as such. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
string newValue = valueSoFar + key.ToString();
```

You are always appending at the end. To append at the right position, you can do something like this:

```
int oldCaretIndex = txtBox.CaretIndex;
txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Insert(text.CaretIndex, "a");
//changing Text resets the caret position to 0
txtBox.CaretIndex = oldCaretIndex + 1;
```

You could also try simulating key presses, see for example here: [How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)

Or, like the commenter suggested, try the SurfaceSDK (though I haven't used it myself).

Comment: Led me in the right direction and solution, thanks! :)