# Global Mouse Hook in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hook

I need to get mouse position on screen **NOT** inside my application.

I've used Global mouse and keyboard hook [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

It works fine under winforms but won't work under wpf.

I'm using version1 of the code and used the following

```
var activity = new UserActivityHook();
activity.OnMouseActivity += activity_OnMouseActivity;
```

but instead of working it give me following error:

> Additional information: The specified module could not be found

under for following code

```
public void Start(bool InstallMouseHook, bool InstallKeyboardHook)
{
    // install Mouse hook only if it is not installed and must be installed
    if (hMouseHook == 0 && InstallMouseHook)
    {
        // Create an instance of HookProc.
        MouseHookProcedure = new HookProc(MouseHookProc);

        //install hook
        hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProcedure,
            Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);
        //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
        if (hMouseHook == 0)
        {
            //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            //do cleanup
            Stop(true, false, false);
            //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
            throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any alternative for WPF or am I missing something?

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SonerGönül i get this error only in wpf.. it works fine in winforms..
so the link won't help my problem here.

Comment: To elaborate on Soner Gonul's largely uninformative response, it looks like you're not initializing UserActivityHook.

Comment: So many thigns wrong - so, here we go with the error....

Comment: You just want to get the [mouse position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your problem but get the latest version from codeplex if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes i have the latest version...  But as i say it works for winforms but not on wpf

Comment: @Blorgbeard not just the mouse position... but i want the global event that triggers mouse movement too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

dotctor's answer gives the mouse position, but not the event I was looking for.

So I figured out on my own. Here are my findings for future reference.

We need to change:

```
//install hook
hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProcedure,
             Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);
```

to the following:

```
// Install hook
hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProcedure, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

Alternatively you can just download the edited cs file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v05e8kc0vogwla5/UserActivityHook.cs?dl=0) then we can use the event

```
activity.OnMouseActivity += activity_OnMouseActivity;
```

under which we can use `e.X` and `e.Y` to get mouse position.

Comment: Link is dead, what a shame. Anything we can do to fix this? (Wayback machine doesn't work).

Comment: @JG3 sorry. I don't have the files anymore. anyways. you'll just need to edit the code as specified above and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get help from a wizard!  (do it the easy way)
   add reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and use `Control.MousePosition`
2. Become an alchemist! (combine your items)
   combine [Visual.PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx) and [Mouse.GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Application.Current.MainWindow`
3. Use an energy chakra (win32)

   ```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
      public Int32 X;
      public Int32 Y;
    };

    public static Point GetMousePosition()
    {
       var w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
       GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);

       return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
    }
   ```

Comment: Yes i can get mouse pointer.. Using the 3rd option u gave..  But what i really want is to report mouse position whenever mouse moves.. Kind of global mouse move event as I've shown in the question... Anyways thanks for the reply its the closest i can get.