# How to get current keyboard cursor point using c# global keyboard hook event

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, keyboard-hook

Im working with a c# application which captures the system events using the global c# mouse and keyboard hooks, But I couldn't get the current keyboard cursor position values while im typing.

Following is my code and it always returns GetCaretPos output as (0,0)

```
PointDetail curPoint = new PointDetail();
Point position = new Point();
IntPtr hwndFoc;
IntPtr hwndFG = WinApiDelegate.GetForegroundWindow();
uint processID = 0;
uint mainWindowProcessId = 0;
IntPtr activeWindowThreadProcess = WinApiDelegate.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndFG, IntPtr.Zero);
IntPtr currWindowThread = IntPtr.Zero;
int thisWindowThread = 0;

this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        currWindowThread = WinApiDelegate.GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
        thisWindowThread = WinApiDelegate.GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.Handle, out mainWindowProcessId);
    }));
int activeWindowThread = WinApiDelegate.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndFG, out processID);

if (activeWindowThread != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
{
    WinApiDelegate.AttachThreadInput(activeWindowThreadProcess, currWindowThread, true);
    hwndFoc = WinApiDelegate.GetActiveWindow();
    bool CaretPos = WinApiDelegate.GetCaretPos(ref position);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer?

Comment: @CosminIoniță Yes. But actually I want the keyboard cursor poison while we are typing. This returns the mouse cursor position and also it will only work on the same form. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the cursor position using the caretPosition. Try the below code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetGUIThreadInfo")]
public static extern bool GetGUIThreadInfo(uint tId, out GUITHREADINFO threadInfo);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]    // Required by user32.dll
        public struct RECT
        {
            public uint Left;
            public uint Top;
            public uint Right;
            public uint Bottom;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]    // Required by user32.dll
        public struct GUITHREADINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint flags;
            public IntPtr hwndActive;
            public IntPtr hwndFocus;
            public IntPtr hwndCapture;
            public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
            public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
            public IntPtr hwndCaret;
            public RECT rcCaret;
        }; 

private System.Windows.Point EvaluateCaretPosition()
        {
            caretPosition = new Point();
            try
            {
                // Fetch GUITHREADINFO
                GetCaretPosition();
                caretPosition.X = (int)guiInfo.rcCaret.Left; //+ 25;
                caretPosition.Y = (int)guiInfo.rcCaret.Bottom; //+ 25;
                WinApiDelegate.ClientToScreen(guiInfo.hwndCaret, ref caretPosition);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                GenerateConsolidatedErrorLog(Ex);
            }
            return new System.Windows.Point(caretPosition.X, caretPosition.Y);
        } 
       public void GetCaretPosition()
        {
            try
            {
                guiInfo = new WinApiDelegate.GUITHREADINFO();
                guiInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(guiInfo);
                // Get GuiThreadInfo into guiInfo
                WinApiDelegate.GetGUIThreadInfo(0, out guiInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                GenerateConsolidatedErrorLog(Ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using some sections from the above code. Great job