# VSTO Word addin - Detect mouse click

Tags: vsto, cpu-word

I'm developing a VSTO Word addin. Is it possible for vsto add-in to detect if user click outside of document region.

Example like in the image below: Detect if I click anywhere inside the black box (ribbon area and the bottom area)

[image]

No need for me to know what control is being clicked... as long as that click happen inside those two black boxes.

Any way for me to that that? Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
Private Function MouseHookCallback(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    If nCode = 0 Then
        Dim mouseHookStruct = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, GetType(SafeNativeMethods.MouseHookStructEx)), SafeNativeMethods.MouseHookStructEx)
        Dim message = CType(wParam, SafeNativeMethods.WindowMessages)
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} event detected at position {1} - {2}", message, mouseHookStruct.pt.X, mouseHookStruct.pt.Y)
        If message = WindowMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN Or message = WindowMessages.WM_MBUTTONDOWN Or message = WindowMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN Or _
            message = WindowMessages.WM_MOUSEHWHEEL Or message = WindowMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
            'do something here
        End If
        If message = WindowMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE Then
            Debug.WriteLine("mouse move!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!a with ncode=> " & nCode)
        End If
    End If

    Return SafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(_hookIdKeyboard, nCode, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't provide anything for that. But you can try to set up a keyboard hook for that, see [Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c) for more information.

```
 using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: THanks @Eugene. 
Ok, i've implemented a mouse hook (WH_MOUSE) instead of low level mouse hook (WH_MOUSE_LL). Managed to detect the click. But the problem now, how do I differentiate if the click happen in those 2 black box or the click is in the document region?

Comment: It seems that doesn't matter where I click, the mouse hook callback will be called. Not sure how to detect which click happen in which region.

Comment: You can try to subclass those two elements where you can handle the click events. Another approach is to check the mouse pointer location, see [Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp) for more information.