# How do I get the Cursor position on a hScrolBar in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

I’m writing a small program rn, where I want to write the position of the cursor in a label. Which property should I use to get the actual position.

PS: Thank you for your help in advanced!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What is the role of the *hScrolBar*? Do you mean the relative position of the Mouse pointer inside a ScrollBar? Or do you simply want to set the value of a ScrollBar to reflect the horizontal position of the Pointer?